# Systemjs angular 2 produces 50 server requests for resources

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I was following the Angular2 quickstart tutorial on Angular.io.

Funny enough, it produces 50 separate requests, I do not understand why.

[image]

Is there a way to bundle everything in one piece? I want to have at most 8 bundles.

here is what it looks like, i just copied this github repo:

https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Comment: Quote from the quickstart, in bold: *This is not the perfect arrangement for your application. It is not designed for production. It exists primarily to get you started quickly with learning and prototyping in Angular*. For production, consider using angular-cli.

Comment: As @JBNizet said, use the angular-cli or create a build process to compile everything and create a bundle after that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution for this.

https://github.com/Anjmao/angular2-production-workflow